# how to reset the search toolbar and search filters in newer versions of free-jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

for older versions of `free-jqgrid` i used a function to reset the search toolbar and filters:

```
function resetSearchToolbar()
{
    var col_arr = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var toolbar_selector;

    for(var i = 0, max = col_arr.length; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(col_arr[i].search && $("#gs_" + col_arr[i].name).val().length)
        {
            toolbar_selector = $("#gs_" + col_arr[i].name)
            toolbar_selector.val("");
        }
    }

    // trigger toolbar searching with key-event:
    if(typeof toolbar_selector !== "undefined")
        toolbar_selector.trigger("keydown");
}
```

this was kind of a very bad hack - but it worked for me.

is there a better way to achieve this in newer versions of free-jqgrid (4.13+)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free jqGrid 4.13.0 implemented new feature: filling the filter toolbar based on the current searching filter `postData.filters` in case of the filter is really applied (`search:true` option is set in jqGrid). If you don't want to have the feature one can use `loadFilterDefaults: true` option of `filterToolbar`.

The feature had some small bugs in some test case, but the version 4.13.2 should have all the problem fixed.

Free jqGrid support `jqGridRefreshFilterValues` event, which can be triggered to force reloading of the filters (without reloading of the grid). On reloading of the grid the filters will be reloaded of cause.

Thus if you changed `postData.filters` or `search` options and you want that the changes will be applied immediately then you need just trigger the `jqGridRefreshFilterValues` event:

```
$("#grid").triggerHandler("jqGridRefreshFilterValues");
```

If you set for example `search: false` before triggering the event then all fields of the filter toolbar will be cleared:

```
var $grid = $("#grid");
$grid.jqGrid("getGridParam").search = false;
$grid.triggerHandler("jqGridRefreshFilterValues");
```

If you would like to clear the filter **and to reload the grid** then you can use old jqGrid method `clearToolbar` instead (see [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention)):

```
$("#grid")[0].clearToolbar();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that:

```
$("#grid").setGridParam({ postData: { filters: {}} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

seems to work out perfectly.