# jqGrid after 'clearToolbar' the toolbar gets no results

Tags: php, laravel, search, jqgrid, toolbar

When opening a create or edit pop-up in a jQgrid, i run `<script>$("#userGrid")[0].clearToolbar(); </script>` to reset the filter/search. This seems to work, but when i try to search something after i close the popup. The search gives me no results unless i refresh the page.

I tried to reload the grid using `$("table[id^=userGrid], table#userGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");` , but this doesn't seem to help. I get "No data found" after search.

Opening a create or edit popup again rests the grid and shows al the rows again, but after closing th popup. Search still shows no results.

Do i use the script wrong or how do i fix this?

Kind regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [how to reset the search toolbar and search filters in newer versions of free-jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787651/how-to-reset-the-search-toolbar-and-search-filters-in-newer-versions-of-free-jqg)

I was using the old method to clear the toolbar. This fixed the issue:

`$("#userGrid").setGridParam({ postData: { filters: {}} }).trigger("reloadGrid");`

This resets the grid, but not the input in the toolbar. At least i can search again.

Comment: Can you please prepare a working example of this, since I'm unclear where you call this method (clearToolbar) -  this is important and it is good to point which version of jqGrid is used.